# obtain task Id for hangfire recurring job inside the task itself

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, hangfire

I have a situation where I have a hangfire recurring task, and for debugging/logging purposes I want to access the Id of that task.

my code to create/register the task is as follows:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(Environment.MachineName, () => MyTask(), Cron.MinuteInterval(_delay));
```

and the code to execute I need to log the task id (which is the machine name, but obviously in a server farm there will be one task registered for each server)

how do I access the id of the task that is running withing the Action that is being executed?

```
public void MyTask()
{
    var taskId = GetTheHangfireTaskIdThatTriggeredThis();  //this is the code I need
    Debug.WriteLine(taskId);
}
```

Ultimately I want to ensure that the tasks only run on the server that registered them as I need the task to execute on every server in the farm (it is to update a local cache on the server itself from a central location).  If there is a better way to achieve this then also please advise me.

Comment: Why cant you just send the MachineName to the method MyTask()?

Comment: @helgehedre yes you can, thank you I had not explored the idea of passing a parameter into the task

Answer (score 0):

changed it to pass a parameter

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(Environment.MachineName, () => MyTask(Environment.MachineName), Cron.MinuteInterval(_delay));
```

and

```
public static void MyTask(string taskId)
    {
        if (!taskId.Equals(Environment.MachineName))
        {
            return;
        }

        Debug.WriteLine(taskId);
    }
```